# I can't get my drupal_http_request to go to the correct function

Tags: hooks, services

I am working with Drupal 7, I have a hook_services_resources() set up:

```
function Api_services_resources() {
  $api = array(
    'applicant' => array(
      'operations' => array(
        'retrieve' => array(
          'help' => 'Updates applicants',
          'callback' => '_Api_retrieve',
          'access callback' => 'user_access',
          'access arguments' => array('access content'),
          'access arguments append' => FALSE,
          'args' => array(
            array(
              'name' => 'gwf',
              'type' => 'text',
              'description' => 'GWF Number',
              'source' => array('path' => 0),
              'optional' => TRUE,
              'default' => '0',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        'create' => array(
          'help' => 'Creates applicants',
          'callback' => '_Api_create',
          'access callback' => 'user_access',
          'access arguments' => array('access content'),
          'access arguments append' => FALSE,
          'args' => array(
            array(
              'name' => 'data',
              'type' => 'array',
              'description' => 'User Account Info',
              'source' => 'data',
              'optional' => FALSE,
              'default' => '0',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        'test' => array(
          'help' => 'Tests API Connection',
          'callback' => '_Api_test',
          'access callback' => 'user_access',
          'access arguments' => array('access content'),
          'access arguments append' => FALSE,
          'args' => array(
            array(
              'name' => 'timestamp',
              'type' => 'text',
              'description' => 'Timestamp',
              'source' => array('path' => 0),
              'optional' => TRUE,
              'default' => '0',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );

  return $api;
}
```

And am trying to post to it using:

```
$create_website_applicant_path = 'http://' . $website_url . '/api/applicant/create/';

      $applicant = array(

        'mail' => $user['applicant_email'],
        'pass' => user_password(8),
        'status' =>  1,
        'roles' =>  array(2 => 1, 3 => 0, 8 => 0, 7 => 0, 6 => 0, 9 => 0),
        'notify' => 0,
        'timezone' => drupal_get_user_timezone(),
        'field_given_name' => array('und' => array('0' => array('value' => $user['first_name']))),
        'field_family_name' => array('und' => array('0' => array('value' => $user['last_name']))),
        'field_gwf' => array('und' => array('0' => array('value' => $user['gwf']))),
        'field_vac_ip' => array('und' => array('0' => array('value' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))),
        'submit' => 'Create new account',
        'ldap_user_create_ldap_acct' => 0,
        'op' => 'Create new account',
        'signature_format' => 'filtered_html',
      );


      $create_website_applicant_params = array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'data' => drupal_http_build_query($applicant),
        'timeout' => 15,
      );
      $create_website_applicant_result = drupal_http_request($create_website_applicant_path, $create_website_applicant_params);
      echo $create_website_applicant_path;
      print_r($create_website_applicant_result);
```

The only problem is that when I try to use POST I get an error saying 404:Not found: Could not find the controller.  I know the page is there, I can go to it in my browser.  If I try to use GET the function being called for /api/applicant/create is actually _Apt_retrieve().  I'm not sure why this is and can't get it to point to the other function.

Answer (score 0):

The path that you are passing in drupal_http_request is incorrect. It should be `$create_website_applicant_path = 'http://' . $website_url . '/api/applicant/';`